# Unable to reset counters in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to amend a list of integers in a way that every 2 duplicating integers will be multiplied by 2 and will replace the duplicates. here is an example: 
    `a = [1, 1, 2, 3] = [2, 2 ,3] = [4 ,3]`
    also : `b = [2, 3, 3, 6 ,9] = [2 , 6 , 6, 9] = [2, 12 , 9]`

I am using the code below to achieve this. Unfortunately, every time I find a match my index would skip the next match.

```
user_input = [int(a) for a in input().split()]

for index, item in enumerate(user_input):
    while len(user_input)-2 >= index:
        if item == user_input[index + 1]:
            del user_input[index]
            del user_input[index]
            item += item
            user_input.insert(index,item)
        break

print(*user_input)
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed that all duplicates will be consecutive? For instance, [1,2,2,3,4] would become [1,4,3,4]. What should that look like after the next step?

Comment: hey Todd, yes I only need to change the consecutive duplicates. [1, 4 , 3, 4] is the final step in your example

Comment: What result do you want for `[8, 4, 2, 1, 1, 7]`? Do you want `[16, 7]` or `[8, 4, 2, 2, 7]`?

Comment: @Etika49 correct me if i'm wrong but i just ran your code in python IDLE and it passed your testcases

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I believe, `[16, 7]`.

Comment: my code is not able to handle multiple matches, however, Rory's code works great. the ultimate goal for b = [2, 3, 3, 6 ,9] is to become b = [2, 12 , 9] and also  [8, 4, 2, 1, 1, 7] has to be 16 , 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, you should never modify a container object while you are iterating over it. There are some exceptions if you know what you are doing, but you certainly should not change the size of the container object. That is what you are trying to do and that is why it fails.

Instead, use a different approach. Iterate over the list but construct a new list. Modify that new list as needed. Here is code that does what you want. This builds a new list named `new_list` and either changes the last item(s) in that list or appends a new item. The original list is never changed.

```
user_input = [int(a) for a in input().split()]

new_list = []
for item in user_input:
    while new_list and (item == new_list[-1]):
        new_list.pop()
        item *= 2
    new_list.append(item)

print(*new_list)
```

This code passes the two examples you gave. It also passes the example `[8, 4, 2, 1, 1, 7]` which should result in `[16, 7]`. My previous version did not pass that last test but this new version does.

Comment: Thank you Rory, i was just wondering why the first version did not pass all the tests. Second Version works great.  I will look the code with debugger now to see why :)

Comment: @Etika49: My first version looked only at the very last item in the new list, while my new version keeps looking back until it finds a list item not equal to the current item.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works Rory!

```
import copy
user_input = [1,1,2,3]
res = []
while res!=user_input:
    a = user_input.pop(0)
    if len(user_input)!=0
        b = user_input.pop(0)
        if a==b:
            user_input.insert(0,a+b)
        else:
            res.append(a)
            user_input.insert(0,b)
    else:
        res.append(a)
        user_input = copy.deepcopy(res)
```

Comment: Why are you asking for Rory to check this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and a recursion:

Check for same consecutive elements:

```
def same_consec(lst):
    return any(len(list(g)) > 1 for _, g in groupby(lst))
```

Replace consecutive same elements:

```
def replace_consec(lst):
    if same_consec(lst):
        lst = [k * 2 if len(list(g)) > 1 else k for k, g in groupby(lst)]
        return replace_consec(lst)
    else:
        return lst
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> a = [8, 4, 2, 1, 1, 7] 
>>> replace_consec(a)
[16, 7]
```